# Hyperapp h function cannot make a component

Tags: hyperapp

I have been trying Hyperapp.

For a number of reasons I want to use the **h** function rather than JSX, I won't get into the whys and wherefores here but no JSX please!

Thing is when I create an instance of a component by using JSX everything is fine.

Example component (both this and the JSX equivalent work the same in examples below):

```
const Examp = (props) => (
  h("p",{},["this is an example"])
 )
```

Example view using JSX, this loads the Examp component as expected (I see 'this is an example'):

```
const view = (state, actions) => (
  <main>
    <h1>JSX Example</h1>
    <p>Begin</p>
    <Examp/>
    <p>End</p>
  </main>
)
```

Example view using h, this doesn't work, I get an empty "examp" node (note the case):

```
const view = (state, actions) => (
  h("main",{},[
    h("h1",{},["H Example"]),
    h("p",{},["Begin"]),
    h("Examp",{},[]),
    h("p",{},["End"])
  ])
)
```

It looks like h is changing the capitalisation of the node and this is causing it not be load the component.

Am I doing something wrong, if so, how should I deal with this?

Edit: having looked at the Hyperapp source code; hyperapp uses document.createElement to create nodes and will always create a lowercase node, as component functions need a capital, have components ever worked with h or has this been overlooked? In which case hyperapp needs JSX :/

Answer (score 0):

As Examp is a component, "h" function should be called using this syntax (without quotes):

```
...
h(Examp, {}, [])
...
```

only HTML base elements should be defined as string.